# is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x + e^x}$ convergent, conditionally convergent or divergent?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

Here is my thinking so far. 
Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{x + e^x}. f(x)$ has a vertical asymptote at $x = -0.5671$

In the range $-\infty \le x \le -0.5671^-$, f(x) behaves like $1/x$ as $x \to -\infty$ and behaves like $1/p(x)$ (where $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree greater than 1) as $x \to -0.5671^-$

I am tempted to conclude this is convergent. 
In the range $-0.5671^+ \le x \le \infty$, $f(x)$ behaves like $1/e^x$ as $x \to \infty$ and behaves like $1/p(x)$ (where $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree greater than 1) as $x \to -0.5671^+$

Ideally I would like to use one of the many conv/div tests to find the answer.

But I am not satisfied with the rigor.

Thank you

Comment: What happens when $x\to-\infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_0^{\infty}$ converges and
$\int_{-\infty}^0$
diverges 
because it acts like
$\dfrac1{x}$
so the sum diverges.

Comment: Yes... As $x \to -\infty$, $\mid \frac{1}{x + e^x} \mid > \mid \frac{1}{x} \mid$ and this is divergent by the comparison test.. Thanks!